Gaps in a `matplotlib` plot of categorical data
When I have numerical data, say index by some kind of time, it is straightforward to plot gaps in the data. For instance, if I have values at times 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, I can set an np.nan at time 4 to break up the plot.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = [10, 20, 30, np.nan, 10, 20, 30]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
plt.close()


That sure beats the alternative of just skipping time 4!
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
y = [10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
plt.close()


However, I now have a y variable that is categorical. Mostly, the plotting is straightforward: just use the categories as the y.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
y = ["cat", "cat", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat"]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
plt.close()


This puts the categories on the y-axis, just as I want. However, when I do my np.nan trick to get the gap, I get a point plotted at np.nan.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = ["cat", "cat", "dog", np.nan, "dog", "cat", "cat"]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
plt.close()


How can I get my plots to go cat cat dog on 1, 2, 3, and then dog cat cat on 5, 6, 7, leaving a gap at 4?

To create a gap in a categorical plot handle np.nan differently asmatplotlib doesn’t natively interpret np.nan in categorical contexts (Gets converted to 'nan' string.).
Solution:
Splitting the data and then plot each segment separately.
x = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
y = ["cat", "cat", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat"]

# Plot each segment separately to introduce a gap
plt.plot(x[:3], y[:3]) 
plt.plot(x[3:], y[3:]) 


Alternative using Masks:
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = ["cat", "cat", "dog", "gap", "dog", "cat", "cat"]

# Convert categorical data to numbers using a mapping
categories = ["cat", "dog"]
y_numeric = [categories.index(val) if val in categories else np.nan for val in y]

y_masked = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(y_numeric), y_numeric)

plt.plot(x, y_masked)
plt.yticks(range(len(categories)), categories)


This allows gaps without splitting anything.

@simon Good spot, thank you. I missed out a line. plt.yticks(range(len(categories)), categories)

The issue is that np.nan gets converted to the 'nan' string by matplotlib.
You could cheat and use numbers to plot, then change the axis labels:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# using _ as placeholder for NaN
# this should be lexicographically sorted before the other values
y = ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', '_', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'pig']

cat, idx = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
# (array(['_', 'cat', 'dog', 'pig'], dtype='<U3'),
#  array([1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 3]))

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(x, np.where(idx>0, idx, np.nan))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(idx.max())+1, cat[1:])

Output:


Why the downvote? Any issue with the answer?
